# Video/Frame rotation in android

Tags: java, android, image, video, frame

Im extracting frames from a video (using javacv) and those are rotated by 180° because the video was taken with a tablet this way.

How can I get the position (if the head is pointing down or not) of a video/frame? Because some videos are ok and others not.

Comment: Many video container formats contain a rotation property that tells you what orientation the video is in.  What is your container format?

Comment: mp4 has a rotation parameter you have to read the rotation parameter so you know the orientation.

Comment: I'm using ffmpeg now. It's binary executed on the device like in a terminal. So it's possible to use all features of ffmpeg.